# Javascript reassign variable and not break reference

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Assuming the following:

```js
let __somevar__ = { hi: 'john' };
Object.defineProperty(window, 'somevar', {
    set: (value)=>{
        __somevar__ = value;
    },
    get: ()=>{
        return __somevar__;
    }
})

let newvar = window.somevar;

// Is it possible to keep the window.somevar reference so that is always uses the setters/getters?
// obviously this actually reassigns newvar instead of using the window.somevar setter.
newvar = { hi: 'senica' }

// These are different now.
console.log(newvar, window.somevar);

// Object.assign won't work because getters/setters are not enumerable.

// A proxy would work, but that's not my question.
```

Not super important...was just curious.

Thanks!

Comment: Not through `=`. But you can create it with the same getters/setters using `defineProperty`

Comment: No. Javascript does not work this way. `let newvar = ...` stores a reference (kind of pointer) to the object returned by `window.somevar`. When assigning `newvar` with a new value you just store a new reference. You have to `window.somevar = newReference`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, can be done with `Object.defineProperty`, just not with `=`:

```js
let __somevar__ = { hi: 'john' };
Object.defineProperty(window, 'somevar', {
    set: (value)=>{
        __somevar__ = value;
    },
    get: ()=>{
        return __somevar__;
    }
})

Object.defineProperty(window, 'newvar', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'somevar'))

newvar = { hi: 'senica' }

console.log(newvar === window.somevar);
```

Comment: OP, keep in mind that while valid, storing variables on `window` isn't good form in modern JS. You should be working with variables in your own scope with a module system. In a normal non-global context, assigning to a variable isn't a behavior you can override, so designing your code to rely on it isn't very futureproof.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
let newvar = window.somevar;
```

the newvar will contains refrence to **somevar**.

With

```
newvar = { hi: 'senica' };
```

You do override newvar value (the reference) to the new object. That doesn't do anything with **somevar**.